# Finding the best point

Tags: geometry

In a place called Ralta, everyone lives on the same (practically infinitely long) straight road. The city council decides to build a garden at some point on the road. To ensure that the garden is easily accessible to everyone, they decide to build it at a point which will minimize the sum of squares of distances from the garden to houses in Ralta.

Task1
Where should the council build the garden?
Assume that the city knows where every resident lives at this point in time.

The council knows where everyone’s houses are, except Sai’s (who moved recently). The council asks Sai where she lives so that they can calculate where to build the garden. Sai wants the garden to be as close to her house as possible, and the city council does not have time to verify if the location Sai reported is correct.

Task 2
What location should Sai report?
Assume that Sai knows where every other resident of Ralta lives.

Edit:i tried it, but i'm not completely sure of my result, i solved for S = x^2+(2x)^2+(3x)^2 and so on aas the sum of the squares. arrived at x^2(n(n+1)(2n+1)/6. After which i differentiated it and equalled it to 0, for which i got negative values. it's a bit messed up

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that we don't know who Sai is, nor do we know what Sai's report should consist of.

Comment: @lulu i'm really sorry, my bad. Changed it now.

Comment: That clears up the Sai business, but you still need to edit to include your efforts.   Surely you can handle the first task, for example.

Comment: i did try it, but i'm not completely sure of my result, i solved for S = x^2+(2x)^2+(3x)^2 and so on aas the sum of the squares. arrived at x^2(n(n+1)(2n+1)/6. After which i differentiated it and equalled it to 0, for which i got negative values. it's a bit messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say there are $n$ people, and the $n$ houses are on co-ordinates $[a_1, a_2, \dots a_n]$. Then we need to find the point $x$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)^2$ is minimum. Evaluating this expression $$\sum_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n(x^2-2xa_i+a_i^2)=\sum_{i=1}^nx^2-\sum_{i=1}^n2xa_i+\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2=nx^2-2x\sum_{i=1}^na_i+\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$$

You can differentiate this 2-degree polynomial and find the root to find the $x_0$ at which it is minimum. $$\frac{d}{dx}(nx^2-2x\sum_{i=1}^na_i+\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2) = 2nx-2\sum_{i=1}^na_i=0$$
$$nx=\sum_{i=1}^na_i \implies x = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}{n}$$

This is the answer to your first question, which will be the mean of all coordinates of the houses. For the second question, Sai can report their house at a point so that the mean of all the houses is equal to the location of her actual house.

Let's take her actual house position $a_0$, the previous mean as $x_m$ and the house she reports as $c$, then the new mean $\frac{nx_m+c}{n+1}$ should be equal to $a_0$, which gives us $c=(n+1)a_0-nx_m$